# Flask and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hey everyone I m little new in this so I hope you all can help me.
I want to pass the data from medicine_name to template to later make a chart but I cant understand how I have to do( I know that I can make a for loop in the template with jinja that I already done but I know I can do it another way and I have obesity problems, until I know all the ways to do it, I dont stop).
Thats my code:

```
class Data(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'two' 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    medicine_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    medicine_amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    medicine_price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    medicine_should = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

The way that I have in mind is something like that:

```
names = Data.query.medicine_name
```

What I m doing wrong ? Hope anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly but hope this helps

You could get all columns from data with:

```py
data = Data.query.all()
```

and then use only `medicine_name` in template

```
{% for d in data %}
  {{ d.medicine_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively you could query only the columns you need

```
names = db.session.query(Data.name).all()
```

You will get list of tuples. So you can loop through list like

```
{% for name in names %}
  {{ name[0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank u so much, it worked !!. Can you explain me why you put [0] in name ? Is  there another way to make the for loop in the flask code instead in html code ?. Thanks anyway

Comment: `name` is a tuple (because you can query multiple columns and you need som way to distinguish them). Maybe I should have named variables differently. In this case you want to access first item in tuple so you need to use `name[0]`. 
This is Jinja code in template. You could use the same loop in python (flask): 
```
for name in names:
  print (name[0])
```
Btw please mark this as answered if it solved your problem.